# how do i combine two selects from one table where one has a GROUP BY and the other has a DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, group-by, distinct

Both of these work individually

```
SELECT  PONumber, 
        count(RequestNumber) as "InNumOfRequests", 
        sum(Amount) as "SumofAmounts" 
FROM tableView
GROUP BY PONumber  

SELECT DISTINCT PONumber, 
                (10 * ceiling((DATEDIFF(day,POApprovedDate,GETDATE()))/10)) 
                  AS "BINofDaysSincePOApproved"                      
FROM tableView
```

And I want to end up with:

```
PONumber   |  InNumOfRequests  |  SumofAmounts  |  BINofDaysSincePOApproved  
PO1        |  2                |  100           |  180
PO2        |  1                |  50            |  179
```

tableView looks like:

```
RequestNumber | PONumber | Amount  |  POApproved Date   
1             | PO1      | 100.00  |  2010-01-01  
2             | PO1      | 100.00  |  2010-01-01  
3             | PO2      |  50.00  |  2010-01-02
```

note that PO1 is actually the PO for 2 requests and so the POApproved Data and Amount is the same for those 2 requests.

It seems easy but from the book I'm using (The Language of SQL) i can't figure it out.
Help :(
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
   FROM (
         SELECT PONumber, count(RequestNumber) as "InNumOfRequests", sum(Amount) as "SumofAmounts"
           FROM tableView
          GROUP BY PONumber
        ) a,
        (
         SELECT DISTINCT PONumber, (10 * ceiling((DATEDIFF(day, POApprovedDate, GETDATE()))/10)) AS "BINofDaysSincePOApproved"
           FROM tableView
        ) b
 WHERE a.PONumber = b.PONumber
```

Comment: Hi Benoit, I get a syntax error at the JOIN.  (and MS SQL Studio doesn't see it as a keyword (it's light gray instead of blue))

Comment: Sweet!!  and the ') a' and ') b' I guess is short for ') AS a' and ') AS b'.  It seems obvious now that you show it like that but I've not seen in the \examples in my book or the google searches where you give a name to the output of a subquery...  Very Cool.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the `AS` keyword is optional.

Answer (score 0):

If the date is ALWAYS equal to each PONumber, can be put in the first select. The MIN function (MIN(POApprovedDate)) is why a group by, then should use aggregate functions in the fields.

```
SELECT  PONumber, 
        count(RequestNumber) as "InNumOfRequests", 
        sum(Amount) as "SumofAmounts",
        (10 * ceiling((DATEDIFF(day,MIN(POApprovedDate),GETDATE()))/10)) 
         AS "BINofDaysSincePOApproved" 
FROM tableView
GROUP BY PONumber
```